# How to test if a document's property changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jestjs

I'm writing tests for an Express CRUD app. The app has an account recovery route that accepts POST requests with an email in the body. It searches for an user with a given email, changes it's password then sends an email with the new password and returns 200.

So I want to write a test that checks if the user's password has indeed changed.

This was my attempt:

First I created a user factory using the `factory-girl` lib.

```
// factory.js file

const { factory } = require('factory-girl');
const User = require('../../models/User');

factory.define('User', User, {
    email: factory.sequence('User.email', n => `fakeuser${n}@mail.com`),
    name: factory.chance('name'),
    password: factory.chance('word')
});

module.exports = factory;
```

Nice. Then I wrote the test:

```
// One test inside my test suite

it('should return 200 and change user\'s password', async () => {
        const user = await factory.create('User');
        const oldPassword = user.password; 

        const response = await request(app)
            .post(endpoint)
            .send({ email: user.email });

        const passwordChanged = oldPassword !== user.password; 

        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(passwordChanged).toBe(true);
        await user.remove();
});
```

But `passwordChanged` is always being evaluated to `false`, since `user.password` doesn't change at all. I mean, on the database, it changes (the method works correctly), but on my test the user object is not updated after the request.

In other words, what I want to test here is the state of a document in the database, not only what the request is returning. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You should mock the DB in the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) and listen for when your fields are changed, then run the comparison right then.